# Rest Assured and float negatie zero

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I want to test my rest service with Rest Assured, but my test fails when service returns negative zero value.

Rest Assured Test:

```
    String methodName="multiply";
    float[] operands = {1f,-2.5f,0};
    float result = operands[0] * operands[1] * operands[2];
    Response response = given().
            pathParam("a",operands[0]).
            pathParam("b",operands[1]).
            pathParam("c",operands[2]).
            contentType(JSON).
            log().ifValidationFails().
        when().
            get("/"+methodName+"/{a}/{b}/{c}").
        then().
            assertThat().statusCode(200).
            body("result",equalTo(result));
```

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path result doesn't match.
Expected: <-0.0F>
  Actual: 0.0
```

Result json:

```
{"result":-0.0}
```

Why the test fails when my rest service returns negative zero value?

Comment: I think a problem is in the way how rest assured's json path convert string '-0' to float.

Comment: On one hand yes, on the other, your service shouldn't return `-0.0f`...

Comment: I was thinking about it. But why not to return -0f? Javascript has this value and we can use it. I also return NaN, +/- Infinity and Rest Assured test them normally and JS can use these values.

Comment: Note `new Float(0.0F).equals(new Double(0.0))` is false. I would use `double` wherever possible instead of float, esp in this case.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Take a look at [Rest Assured docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#note-on-floats-and-doubles) about floats and doubles, please. They say that we should compare with a float.

Comment: @SlavaBabin Java, Javascript, JSON, and your error message all use `double` or 64-bit floating point by default. I can see no reason to use `float`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I use float in my Test class because Rest Assured fails if you use float when check result. If i use double and get `{"result": -86.55952111819283}` then my test fails - `Expected: <-86.55952111819283>  Actual: -86.559525`

Comment: @SlavaBabin interesting, I think it's a bug if it is rounding your values like that. a value on Javascript is a 64-bit floating point and any JSON parser should treat it as such. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159.html#section-6 states "This specification allows implementations to set limits on the range
   and precision of numbers accepted.  Since software that implements
   IEEE 754-2008 binary64 (double precision) numbers [IEEE754] is
   generally available and widely used, "

Comment: @PeterLawrey In Rest Assured we can use BigDecimal. I think this is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out that it is better to configure REST Assured to return all Json numbers as BigDecimal and then use hamcrest closeTo matcher.

```
String methodName="multiply";
double[] operands = {1,-2.5,0};
double result = operands[0] * operands[1] * operands[2];
Response response = given().
        config(RestAssured.config().jsonConfig(jsonConfig().numberReturnType(BIG_DECIMAL))).
        pathParam("a",operands[0]).
        pathParam("b",operands[1]).
        pathParam("c",operands[2]).
        contentType(JSON).
        log().ifValidationFails().
    when().
        get("/"+methodName+"/{a}/{b}/{c}").
    then().
        assertThat().statusCode(200).
        log().ifValidationFails().
        body("result",closeTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(result),new BigDecimal("1E-20")));
```

Comment: Where does the parameterless `jsonConfig()` come from? I used `new JsonConfig(BIG_DECIMAL)` instead

Comment: @pwes `import static io.restassured.config.JsonConfig.jsonConfig` you can also look at example [here](https://github.com/babinslava/webcalc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/upwork/WebCalculatorApplicationTests.java)

Comment: The static method is no more there, as of 3.0.2. Probably API changed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As per latest Rest Assured  rules we will get round-off value directly.However if you want to validate exact JSON repose(In Banking aplications) without round-off logic then we have to use below code:-

```
BigDecimal xyz=JsonPath.with(response.asString()).using(new JosnPathConfig.NumberReturnType.BigDecimal)).get("JSON PATH")
```

Here response=JSON response and JSON PATH is nothing but exact json filed which want to validate through response.